# Subgradients of non-convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, subgradient

In [these notes](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_notes.pdf) (section 2.3), it is stated that:

> *A point $x^*$ is a minimizer of a function $f$ (**not necessarily convex**) if and only if $f$ is subdifferentiable at $x^*$ and $0 \in\partial f(x^*).$*

Could anybody provide me with references for a proof of the above statement?

Is there a reference where we can learn more about subgradients of non-convex functions? 
In Section **3. Calculus of subgradients** of the above notes,many properties of subgradients are presented for convex functions. I would like to know which ones among these properties still hold for non-convex functions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's not much to tell w.r.t. general references. The basic definition of a subgradient, at the top of those notes, applies to any function, convex or otherwise.

Comment: What isn't clear about the text's explanation of this claim? I thought about writing out the answer but then I realized it would pretty much be exactly what is written there.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks. I was actually looking for a proof of that statement.

Comment: But it's basically right there in the text. It's not a *formal* proof but the details are there.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: You are right, it's trivial (:facepalm:). Before posting the question, I had also read these slides: http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_slides.pdf, and I saw, on page 22, at the end of the proof it is written ". . . seems trivial but isn’t", which made me think that it was an unfinished proof and the "true" proof would be longer and more complicated. I was wrong. I'm still wondering why they wrote ". . . seems trivial but isn’t" :\

Comment: Keep in mind that just because the notion that $0\in\partial f(x^*)$ is trivial to establish doesn't mean that subgradient *methods* are useful for nonconvex functions. After all, once you hit a point where a subgradient doesn't exist, you're stuck.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thanks. Actually I was not trying to apply subgradient methods to nonconvex functions. The above question arose when I was reading the convergence analysis of ADMM in Boyd et al.'s paper. I have realized that the convexity assumption in that analysis is not necessary (but I may be wrong). Could you please have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759829/on-boyd-et-al-s-convergence-analysis-of-admm-why-do-we-need-the-convexity-assu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^* \text{ minimizes } f(x) \Longleftrightarrow 0\in\partial f(x^*)$$
is trivial by definition of subgradients: $$f(x) - f(x^*) \ge \partial f(x^*)^T (x-x^*)\quad \forall x.$$

Thanks to Michael Grant for his comments.

Answer (score -2):

The answer above is true only when $f$ is convex.

Comment: Why do you say so? The accepted answer does not require the assumption that $f$ is convex.