# On Boyd et al.'s convergence analysis of ADMM: Why do we need the convexity assumption?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Please refer to [Boyd et al.'s convergence analysis of ADMM](http://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) (Chapter 3 and Appendix A).

My question is: Why do we need $f$ and $g$ to be convex?

I don't see the need of this assumption. **If the convexity assumption is removed, the analysis is still valid.**

Thanks.

P/s: related: [Subgradients of non-convex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754538/subgradients-of-non-convex-functions)

Comment: Doesn't the proof utilize subgradients? (And not just at the minimizer?)

Comment: @MichaelGrant : The proof uses optimality conditions based on subgradients, which also hold for nonconvex functions.

Comment: Honestly, I think it is incumbent on you to prove that the convexity assumption is not necessary. It seems rather evident to me that it is. You're telling me that I get convergence no matter what shape the non-convex function is? Even if it has local optima?

Comment: @MichaelGrant : Yes, ADMM converges to a KKT point. If the functions are convex then this KKT point is also globally optimal. Getting a KKT point is already not bad for nonconvex functions, isn't it?

Comment: The proof that the convexity assumption is not necessary: is right in the paper: just remove the convexity and the proofs of the inequalities (A1), (A2), (A3) still hold.

Comment: In the proof of (A2) for example, they wrote: "Since f is closed, proper, and convex it is subdifferentiable, and so is Lρ. The (necessary and sufficient) optimality condition is <conditions involving subgradients>." However, <conditions involving subgradients> hold whether f is convex or not (c.f. The p/s in my question).

Comment: Well, given that you are contradicting chapter 9 of that very document (and, frankly, common sense about nonconvexity)  I remain convinced you have more work to do.

Comment: @MichaelGrant : Tomorrow I'll read the paper again and try to carefully write down a complete proof of convergence for nonconvex functions (I'm replying you while on my bed using my phone :P). Thanks a lot for your discussion!

Comment: Sounds good! Good luck!

Comment: @MichaelGrant: I have written a complete proof of the global convergence of ADMM for non-convex functions. In addition, I showed that the rate of convergence is at least $O(1/\sqrt{k})$. Please have a look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8u0nh3mi33dsqxf/admm_nonconvex.pdf?dl=0 I'm looking forward to hearing your opinions :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their proof uses subgradients of a function $f$ and their properties. If $f(x)$ is not convex, then not everywhere can you define its subgradient. Think about $f(x) = -x^2$, which is a concave function and not convex; the gradient $f'(x) = -2x$ is not a subgradient (sounds weird, doesn't it?) because $f'(x) = -2x$ does not satisfy the subgradient definition (and its key property) $f(y) \ge f(x) + \langle -2x, y-x\rangle$ for all $y$. In fact this inequality only holds for $y=x$.

Traditionally, ADMM is used for, and was proved to converge with, convex functions. In fact, convexity is not a necessary condition for ADMM to work. Google for "nonconvex ADMM" or "nonconvex nonsmooth ADMM" and you will see some recent papers.

Comment: At a high-level, this is a correct answer. Thanks.